# Issue with my filters on cards and pagination code

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, pagination

I am new to coding into html, css and javascript. I am trying to build a Portfolio page where I can showcase my projects undertaken. The problem I am facing is when I try to apply filters on the cards (projects) and playing with the pagination, because it does not keep the filters applied.

The full website files are stored here: https://github.com/Pablonevadobusto/PNB
These files are needed to run the web (especially a js file called "mixitup.min.js", because it's needed to make the filters working)

The potential outcome I am after is that I want to have 6 cards maximum per page, regardless the filter. E.g. currently I have 8 projects (5 Science and 3 Analysis) and the filter options are "All", "Science" and "Analysis"; if I filtered on "All" I would want the outcome to be 6 cards in the 1st page and 2 leftover cards in the 2nd page. Also, if I filtered on "Science" I would want it to display 5 Science cards and then it would just have 1 page. Finally, if I filtered on "Analysis" the desired outcome would be 3 Analysis cards and just offer 1 page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- box icons -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <!-- custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>


    <!-- header design -->
        
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#portfolio"></a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- portfolio section design -->
    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <h2 class="heading">Latest <span>Projects</span></h2>

        <div class="work__filters">
            <span class="work__item active-work"data-filter='all'>All</span>
            <span class="work__item"data-filter='.science'>Science</span>
            <span class="work__item"data-filter='.analysis'>Analysis</span>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-container">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card mix science">
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <h3>Science</h3>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-layer">
                        <p>description</p>
                            
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="card mix science">
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <h3>Science</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-layer">
                        <p>description</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="card mix science">
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <h3>Science</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-layer">
                        <p>description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mix science">
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <h3>Science</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-layer">
                        <p>description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mix science">
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <h3>Science</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-layer">
                        <p>description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mix analysis">
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <h3>Analysis</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-layer">
                        <p>description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mix analysis">
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <h3>Analysis</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-layer">
                        <p>description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mix analysis">
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <h3>Analysis</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-layer">
                        <p>description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>       

        
            <div class="pagination">
                <!-- <li class="page-item previous-page disable"><a class="page-link" href="#">Prev</a></li> 
                <li class="page-item current-page prompt"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li> 
                <li class="page-item dots"><a class="page-link" href="#">...</a></li> 
                <li class="page-item current-page"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li> 
                <li class="page-item current-page"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li> 
                <li class="page-item dots"><a class="page-link" href="#">...</a></li> 
                <li class="page-item current-page"><a class="page-link" href="#">10</a></li>
                <li class="page-item next-page"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>  -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getPageList(totalPages, page, maxLength){
            function range(start, end){
                return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start);
            }

            var sideWidth = maxLength < 9 ? 1 : 2;
            var leftWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth * 2 - 3) >> 1;
            var rightWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth * 2 - 3) >> 1;

            if(totalPages <= maxLength){
                return range(1, totalPages);
            }

            if(page <= maxLength - sideWidth - 1 -rightWidth){
                return range(1, maxLength - sideWidth - 1).concat(0, range(totalPages - sideWidth + 1, totalPages));
            }

            if(page >= totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth){
                return range(1, sideWidth).concat(0, range(totalPages - sideWidth - 1 -rightWidth - leftWidth, totalPages));
            }

            return range(1, sideWidth).concat(0, range(page - leftWidth, page + rightWidth), 0, range(totalPages - sideWidth + 1, totalPages));
        }

        $(function(){
            var numberOfItems = $(".card-content .card").length;
            var limitPerPage = 6; //How many card items visible per page
            var totalPages = Math.ceil(numberOfItems / limitPerPage);
            var paginationSize = 3; //How many page elements visible in the pagination
            var currentPage;

            function showPage(whichPage){
                if(whichPage < 1 || whichPage > totalPages)return false;

                currentPage = whichPage;

                $(".card-content .card").hide().slice((currentPage - 1) * limitPerPage, currentPage * limitPerPage).show();

                $(".pagination li").slice(1, -1).remove();

                getPageList(totalPages, currentPage, paginationSize).forEach(item => {
                    $("<li>").addClass("page-item").addClass(item ? "current-page" : "dots")
                    .toggleClass("prompt", item === currentPage).append($("<a>").addClass("page-link")
                    .attr({href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text(item || "...")).insertBefore(".next-page");
                });

                $(".previous-page").toggleClass("disable", currentPage === 1);
                $(".next-page").toggleClass("disable", currentPage === totalPages);
                return true;
            }

            $(".pagination").append(
                $("<li>").addClass("page-item").addClass("previous-page").append($("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text("Prev")),
                $("<li>").addClass("page-item").addClass("next-page").append($("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text("Next"))
            );

            $(".card-content").show();
            showPage(1);

            $(document).on("click", ".pagination li.current-page:not(.prompt)", function(){
                return showPage(+$(this).text());
            });

            $(".next-page").on("click", function(){
                return showPage(currentPage + 1); 
            });
            
            $(".previous-page").on("click", function(){
                return showPage(currentPage - 1); 
            });
        });
        </script>
    </section>

    <!-- scroll reveal -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>

    <!-- MIXITUP FILTER  -->

    <script src="js/mixitup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom js -->
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --bg-color: #fdfdfd;
    --text-color: #333;
    --main-color: #edbf2b;
    --white-color: #fdfdfd;
    --shadow-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    background: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem 3%;
    background: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: .5s;
}

.header.sticky {
    background: var(--bg-color);
    box-shadow: 0 .1rem 1rem var(--shadow-color);
}

span {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.heading {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.work__filters {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: .75rem;
}

.work__item {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: .5rem;
}

.active-work {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.portfolio-container {
    min-height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 2px;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;                       
}

.card-image {
    max-height: 265px;
}

.card-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    border-radius: 2rem;
}

.card:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.card-info {
    position: relative;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding: 0px 20px 5px;
}

.card-info h3 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .portfolio-layer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.1), var(--main-color));
    color: var(--white-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.card:hover .portfolio-layer {
    opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-layer p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin: .3rem 0 1rem;
}

.portfolio-layer a {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background: var(--white-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.portfolio-layer a i {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #333;
}


.pagination {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 30px 60px;
    user-select: none;
}

.pagination li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(1 1 1 / 10%);
}

.pagination li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.previous-page, .next-page {
    background: var(--main-color);
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 45px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.previous-page:hover{
    transform: translateX(-5px);
}

.next-page:hover{
    transform: translateX(5px);
}

.current-page, .dots {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.prompt {
    background: var(--main-color);
}

.disable {
    background: #ccc;
```

```
/*=========== MIXITUP FILTER PORTFOLIO ==============*/

let mixerPortfolio = mixitup('.card-content', {
    selectors: {
        target: '.card'
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 300
    }
});

/* Link active work */
const linkWork = document.querySelectorAll('.work__item')

function activeWork(){
    linkWork.forEach(l=> l.classList.remove('active-work'))
    this.classList.add('active-work')
}

linkWork.forEach(l=> l.addEventListener('click', activeWork))
```